# Need Javascript Regex Replace to wrap certains words with <a...>

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

We have a database where every table name starts with WW.
I want to display an SQL on a web page, but wrap each table name with a link.
For example:

```
"select * from wwx_something where ..."
```

Should be transformed into:

```
"select * from <a href='/table/wwx_something/'>wwx_something</a> where ..."
```

There might be several tables, of course, and it should not be case-sensitive.

I need a javascript regex solution...I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216007/surrounding-all-instances-of-and-http-with-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using a single [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
var re = /(FROM|JOIN)\s+(WW\S+)/gi;
yourText.replace(re, "$1 <a href='$2'>$2</a>");
```

note that I also tentative support for stuff such like "SELECT * FROM wwa JOIN wwb".

ADDED after comment: yes, you can replace with a custom function in order to uppercase the URL:

```
var re = /(FROM|JOIN)\s+(WW\S+)/gi;
function change(s, p1, p2) {
    return p1 + " <a href='http://whatever/" + p2.toUpperCase() + "'>" + p2 + "</a>";
}
yourText.replace(re, change);
```

PS: IMHO it's better to include FROM/JOIN in the match because this way you're better warded about strays "ww" that have nothing to do with table names... including a bit of context always helps disambiguate.

Comment: Yes, this is more like it! ( but I only need one group, I don't need to match the (FROM|JOIN) ).
( I was not using "$1" in my replacement string because I thought I needed "\1" )
One more thing....can I convert one of the $1 to lower-case? (the one in the generated URL )